# Is it possible to do rigid body sims with periodic border conditions?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

is there any native way or quick hack to get Blenders rigid body sim to use periodic border conditions, meaning that an object that leaves the domain to the left enters back in to the right, if it leaves at the back it comes back in at the front?

Comment: Blender does not use a domain for the rigid body function.

Comment: So, I guess that means there is no way to do something like this?

Comment: Not without a complex script

Comment: problem is also, you can not simply move them over if they leave the domain as it could intersect after moving over

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Yes, it is an XY problem. What I want to do is this: I have seen Andrew Prices Tutorial about creating infinite amounts of donuts in Blender. It struck me that there is a much easier way to do seamless textures with rigid bodiesthan what he did: Just make the boundary conditions periodic.

Comment: That means every donut intersecting the border of the texture tile would automatically show up at the other side as well, so the texture would be seamless by first principles. But I am not sure if this is possible in Blenders rigid body physics. The donuts near the border would have to collide with donuts on both sides of the tile. So the way of calculating vertex distances would need to work through the boundary, so to speak. Actually, this might not be worth the effort, I fear.